# Overriding RolesAllowedDynamicFeature in Jersey 2.5.1

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Short and sweet:

I want to be able to filter incoming requests to authenticate the user then take the roles defined in my database and use them in the Jersey 2.5.1 Service classes.

e.g.

```
@RolesAllowed("Custom1", "Custom2")
@Post
```

.....

Currently I have the following, which seems to work with the basic @PermitAll and @DenyAll annotations, I am just not sure how to overload/what to overload to get some custom code working with Jersey 2.5.1. I've seen examples for Jersey1. Should I just create a request Filter and do it in there and set the securityContext? Any help would be appreciated.

```
   public class TestApi extends ResourceConfig {
    public TestApi() {
        super(AuthenticateResource.class);
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my problem. Injected Resource Info then pulled out the annotation. This works if it's not pre-matching

```
@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

Annotation[] annotations = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getDeclaredAnnotations();
```

Answer (score 0):

[SecurityContext](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) is either set by the underlying container or it's set manually in your application (usually in [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html)). If your container is sophisticated enough to set the correct security context for you (with correct principal) you can go this way. Otherwise create a custom `ContainerRequestFilter` similar to the one in Jersey example [ContainerAuthFilter](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/flight-mgmt-webapp/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/flight/providers/ContainerAuthFilter.java#L69).